# How we select LC filter for MAX3221?

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, frequency, rs232

I have seen a schematic where they used MAX3221IPWRG4 (Texas Instruments), RS232 Driver and Receiver. There they have used LC filter of inductor value 0.68uH and capacitor value of 680pF, but in datasheet they have not mentioned about frequency. Can anyone explain how they selected this value?
[image]

Comment: Which schematic? On some device or datasheet? Where is the LC filter, on RS232 lines, data lines, positive supply, or ground?

Comment: Hi in ethernet switch, a console RJ45 is connected to UART through this IC. In the pin DOUT and DIN the inductor 0.68uH and 680pF is used

Comment: You could just post the schematic picture or otherwise draw it. I still don't understand where exactly the filter is, on TTL side or on RS232 side. Maxim MAX3221 datasheet does not have DOUT and DIN pins.

Comment: I just added it, it is MAX3221IPWRG4 texas instruments

Comment: Please share a link to the schematic with the LC components shown so we have some context.

Comment: Looks like equivalent of twisted pair. No additional elements needed.

Answer (score 1):

The filter is a low pass filter with a frequency cutoff around 7.4MHz, so the designer though that it would be good to filter out frequencies beyond 7MHz. On problem with an LC filter is it has a resonance point which gives it some overshoot and is probably not needed in most applications.

There is nothing in the datasheet to suggest that an LC filter is needed for proper operation of the MAX3221 and was something added by the designer of the schematic for their purposes.